# memory leak when declaring and assigning an object

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

*please note: this is a specific question about my app, but may be useful for other novice developers*

I am unable to find the reason for my "memory leak".

I noticed while debugging this leak, a simple orientation change uses `0.01mb` memory.

This bit of code below takes up 0.04mb memory

```
//global
WifiManager wifiManager;
List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigList;
WifiInfo wifiInfo;

private void refreshWifiInfo() {
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiConfigList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
}
```

And a few other methods aswel, all run in a thread. This thread sleeps and executes ever `1000ms`, the total usage of this thread per loop is +/- 0.09mb-0.11mb.

- [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sajDV.jpg) is a screenshot taken when the app executes,
- [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1achG.jpg) the app is idle.
- [Starting the scan thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJbqe.jpg) (via button click at 1:24), memory starts filling up, here we see memory filling up by +/- 3Mb per minute.
- [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/051Pl.jpg) memory heap is almost completely full

***note:*** all these "tests" are with no input, no extra dialogs, popups, monitors, just the thread scanning and displaying results. NO bitmaps/images/graphics are used!

as time progresses, memory keeps filling up to a point of `OutOfMemory Exception`

I have tried dumping the memory heap and analyzing it with Eclipse Memory Analyzer, that which it suspects as the memory leak is [arrays of bytes containing periods](http://pastebin.com/MfiYh42V)

Another scan I ran shows [massive memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey4KD.jpg) in a short period of time (+/-1m30s)

My Thread contains:

```
 t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
                while (!bStopThread) {
                    System.gc();
                    ThreadCounter++;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (bSafe) {
                                initWiFiArrays();
                                CreateSetAdapter();
                                threadRefresh.setText("# Refreshed Times : " + String.valueOf(ThreadCounter));
                                writeResultsToFile();
                            } else
                                stopScan();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(scanInterval);
                    } catch (Exception x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

Looking at the code from the start of the post, calling:

```
refreshWifiInfo();
```

alone used 0.04mb, this does not seem normal!

No context's are being sent to other classes, no static/final variables declared, although I do have globally defined TextViews, EditTexts, a button, only where is necessary and cannot be done otherwise.

How can I detect these memory leaks, since I am at a loss?

*p.s. I have been at it all day, still have not found anything*